# Setting value in very first cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

in my Python script I'm initializing a dictionary which will be managed afterwards as a nested dictionary. After updating and working with it I want to save it as a csv file as a permanent storage so I can read it in again later and then update again and so on.

My problem is the following. For working with the nested dictionary it has the following structure:

```
dict = {
    'key1': {
        'grp1': 0,
        'grp2': 2
    }
}
```

Using pandas I can perfectly export this as a csv file using `data = pd.DataFrame(dict)` which I can then use as a table in Libre Calc or Excel where it looks like this:

|  | key |
| --- | --- |
| grp1 | 2 |
| grp2 | 4 |

However, I would like to also have a header in (table) cell `0,0` (the top left cell in the table above) so that I can sort, group, do other stuff in Excel and such.

But I cannot figure out how do to that in an easy and quick way.

`DataFrame.iat` does not do that since it seems to only access values in the cells aside from the headers/labels.

I also could read in the csv file, split the lines, add "headername" at the beginning and output the csv file again but this seems to me like too much use of space/memory.

It also does not seem to be possible to read in the first line of the csv, which is the headers, and change just that and write it back to the csv without touching the rest, or am I getting this wrong?

Isn't there something similar to `DataFrame.iat` or the deprecated `DataFrame.set_value` which does the job in one line?

I also hope the question title is alright!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1': {'grp1': 0,
                            'grp2': 2
                           }
                  })


df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'your_value'})
```

```
    your_value  key1
0   grp1        0
1   grp2        2
```

And when you save the file using `df.to_csv()` pass `index=False` and you won't have those `0 and 1` indexes in the very left.

Comment: As far as I understand this renames the column `index` to `your_value`. I tried this with `data.reset_index().rename(columns={'':'your_value'})` as the column I want to rename as no name but it doesn't work. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: After you use `reset_index()` pandas automatically names the column `index`. So you should use `index` in your case too.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this also does not seem to work after I tried. I just copied the lines from your solution but `print(df)` still returns a dataframe in a state as before the `reset_index` line, without a `your_value` column anywhere.

Comment: Yes, because those functions do not change `df` inplace, if you want to change the `df` simply assign `df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'your_value'})`